# how to check if there exists 2nd highest score in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has a int column representing for scores of student. I want to select the 2nd highest score if there does exists for 2nd highest score, and if not, return null. Wondering how to implement in SQL.

I am using MySQL/SQL Workbench.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this constant spoon feeding is going to help you in the long run. You have to make some effort to learn and figure these things out for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query would return the second highest value if present or-else NULL

```
SELECT MAX(score)
FROM table_name
WHERE score<>(
SELECT MAX(score)
FROM table_name);
```

Comment: @Mattew, I tried your code it works. And it will return Null if there is only one record in the table. I think your code works the same as Rubin's code, but his code return nothing when there is only one record in the table. Do you know why returns are different?

Answer (score 1):

Please try executing following sql query for retrieving 2nd highest score

```
SELECT score from table order by score desc limit 1,1
```

The above query will return 2nd highest score if it exists or **NULL** if it the record does not exists

Comment: thanks for the quick response, in your logic, what do you mean logically 2nd highest score does not exists? Does it mean all students have the same score?

Comment: the score could be duplicate, and not sure if your code works to handle this case?

Comment: @LinMa No it will just return 2nd highest score sorted by score in descending order

Comment: thanks and if everyone has the same score, your code will return the same score, correct?

Comment: @LinMa It will result a single result containing 2nd highest score and if every student has same score it will return same value

Comment: I tried your code and it returns nothing if there is only one record in the table. I think your code should have the same effect of Mattew's code, but his code returns Null when there is only one record in the table. Do you know why?

Comment: BTW, I think you should use limit 2,1? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa It will be  limit 1,1 only since row index begins from 0

Comment: thanks. :) It will be great if you could comment on my question about the differences between your code and Mattew's code as I asked above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When there is top 2 highest scores then the second one will be displayed
other wise ie: if it has single maximum value overall the table then it displays null..

```
select top 1 case when row_number() over (order by tbl.score asc) =2 then a else null end ,row_number() over (order by tbl.score asc) as ranks from (

select  top 2 score from table group by score  order by 1 desc

)tbl
order by 1 desc
```

I have selected top two records of desc then taking second record..

If it is not present then it will displays null

Comment: thanks for your reply and in your logic, what do you mean logically 2nd highest score does not exists? Does it mean all students have the same score?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Agree with @FrancescoMenzani. koushik veldanda, appreciate if you could clarify more for your code, I still feel a bit lost for your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following query

SELECT max(score) FROM table WHERE score NOT IN (SELECT max(score) FROM table);

OR

SELECT max(score) FROM table WHERE score < (SELECT max(score) FROM table);

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this on how to display the nth highest value not only the 2nd.  We could use the min code instead of the  max.

```
Select * from employee where salary= (Select min(salary) from (select * from employee order by salary desc limit 2) as MyTop);
```

this can modified for any nth highest value wanted by only changing the desc limit to the "nth" needed.

Comment: Sometimes sub select are not the best solution